# Process large ROI in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, geoprocessing, vci

I am calculating the VCI for Europe, but the ROI is too large for a single run in GEE. How can I divide it and process it in chunks so that when downloaded they fit into a single image/composite?

```
var bbox = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
  [-12.8,35.1],
  [-12.8, 71.5],
  [49.5,71.5],
  [49.5, 35.1],
  [-12.8,35.1]]);
  
Map.centerObject(bbox);
Map.addLayer(bbox, {color: 'FF0000'}, 'geodesic polygon');

// Assign a common name to the sensor-specific bands.
var LC8_BANDS = ['B2',   'B3',    'B4',  'B5',  'B6',    'B7',    'B10']; //Landsat 8
var LC5_BANDS = ['B1',   'B2',    'B3',  'B4',  'B5',    'B7',    'B6']; //Llandsat 5
var STD_NAMES = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'nir', 'swir1', 'swir2', 'temp'];

var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA').filterDate('1990-1-1', '2000-12-31')
                                                      .filterBounds(bbox);// Landsat 8
var l5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA').filterDate('1990-1-1', '2000-12-31')
                                                      .filterBounds(bbox); //Landsat 5    
var withCloudiness = l8.map(function(image) {
  var cloud = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(image).select('cloud');
  var cloudiness = cloud.reduceRegion({
    reducer: 'mean', 
    geometry: bbox, 
    bestEffort: true,
    scale: 30,
  });

  return image.set(cloudiness);
});

var filteredCollectionl8 = withCloudiness.filter(ee.Filter.lt('cloud', 20)).select(LC8_BANDS, STD_NAMES);

var withCloudiness = l5.map(function(image) {
  var cloud = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(image).select('cloud');
  var cloudiness = cloud.reduceRegion({
    reducer: 'mean', 
    geometry: bbox, 
    bestEffort: true,
    scale: 30,
  });

  return image.set(cloudiness);
});

var filteredCollectionl5 = withCloudiness.filter(ee.Filter.lt('cloud', 20)).select(LC5_BANDS, STD_NAMES);

var lall = ee.ImageCollection(filteredCollectionl5.merge(filteredCollectionl8));

var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['nir', 'red']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi).toFloat();
};

var ndviColl = lall.map(addNDVI);

// Define a combined reducer for min and max - one pass through the data.
var minMaxReducer = ee.Reducer.min().combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.max(),
  sharedInputs: true
});


// Calculate regional min and max and add as image properties.
ndviColl = ndviColl.map(function(img) {
  var minMax =  img.reduceRegion(
    {reducer: minMaxReducer, geometry:bbox, bestEffort:true, scale: 30});
  return img.set({
    roi_min: minMax.get('NDVI_min'),
    roi_max: minMax.get('NDVI_max')
  });
});


// Filter out min and max region reductions that are null.
var filtered = ndviColl
  .filterMetadata('roi_min', 'not_equals', null)
  .filterMetadata('roi_max', 'not_equals', null);
  
// Create VCI index.
var vci = filtered.map(function(img){
 var id = img.id();
 var max = img.getNumber('roi_max');
 var Index = img.expression("(NDVI-min)/(max-min)", {
    "NDVI": img.select('NDVI'),
    "min" : img.getNumber('roi_min'),
    "max" : img.getNumber('roi_max'),
 })
 .rename('VCI')
 .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
 return Index;
});

vci = vci.filterDate('2000-1-1', '2000-12-31');

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: vci.mean(),
  description: 'imageToDriveExample',
  scale: 30,
  region: bbox,
  maxPixels: 900000000
});
    
// Display the result.
var ndviParams = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};
var vciParams = {min: 0, max:1}
Map.addLayer(vci.mean(), vciParams, 'VCI image');
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: These 2:
VCI image: Tile error: Computation timed out.
VCI image: Tile error: User memory limit exceeded.

If I use a smaller bbox I get the image result.

Comment: That is when you try to export it?

Comment: No, just to run it online.

Comment: What do you get if you try to export it? With big computations like you are doing, which can take a long time, it is better to export the results. This allows the computation to run for longer than if you try to visualize the results

Comment: I ran it yesterday and it is still going on. I suppose it's working. I'll let you know what I get.